# Redirect to HTTPS fails Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I got the following setup for my security:

```
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/registration/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                    .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied")
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/error-login");
        }
```

Now problem is when i deploy it on production server when i try open demo.com or http://demo.com or combination of such, i get too many redirects and it fails.

On Chrome: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

On Firefox: The page isn't redirecting properly

In other words it redirects until it fails.

Any advice on what could be wrong here or what i could do to figure out the problem?

**EDIT 1:**

Controller request

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"})
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Log: No entries (other than standard bootup sequence)

Comment: From this config doesn't look bad. Could you publish your error log and code for your controllers? May be there is something wrong.

Comment: The log is empty, and as for controller refer to EDIT 1

Comment: When strange problems like this are occurred I would recommend set the lowest possible level of logging and replay step-by-step the whole process with debugger.

Comment: Done that already, nothing in the logs at all. I'm thinking could be our vendors server. Do you maybe have any ideas around there that could be cause?

Comment: You say it fails with demo.com, are there any app-related URLs (whatever they are) for which it works? Or it's failing with everything? Also, good to confirm the problem is with the authentication--if you remove the .antMatchers() line, does it work then?

Comment: Unsure if this is the problem, but I believe an infinite redirect loop can happen if the page you configure Spring to redirect to in case the user hasn't authenticated yet is itself incorrectly configured to need authentication e.g., shopping checkout --> login --> login --> login --> ... as a result.

Comment: @GlenMazza yes it fails for all, I will check the antMatcher aspect. Out of curiosity does this mean that pages that are not meant to be  authenticated shouldn't be using secure channel (/index.html, /about.html, /contact.html)?

Comment: @Aeseir Whether or not HTTPS is used I would think is a separate issue from authentication, so no.

Comment: Confirmed  authorization didn't affect it. Been forced to disable secure channel and use server level redirects

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify port mapping in your WebSecurityConfigurer with the corresponding HTTP and HTTPS ports of your application:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/registration/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
                .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
            .and()
                .portMapper()               
                .http(8080).mapsTo(8443);
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied")
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/error-login");
    }
```

`http.portMapper().http(8080).mapsTo(8443)` maps your HTTP 8080 port to HTTPS 8443 port to correctly perform the redirect.

Read more:

- https://myshittycode.com/2014/06/12/spring-security-forcing-urls-to-use-https/
- http://www.rmarcello.it/spring-security-aumomatic-redirect-on-https/